# Sizing Water Supply

Tags: plumbing

First attempt calculating water line size.

Background:

- Single family residence
- Built in 1955
- All building piping is 1/2" galvanized steel
- 3/4" water meter/service
- Supply line from meter to building replaced with 3/4" pex-a

Continually dropping flow rates (likely due to corrosion/hard water scaling) suggest replacing all building plumbing. Currently considering pex-a.

Looking at UPC Table 610.4, I see two entries which might be applicable:

- 3/4" meter/service and 3/4" building supply
- 3/4" meter/service and 1" building supply

Questions:

- Am I interrupting the table correctly: can you connect a 1" building supply to a 3/4" meter?
- If so, would it make sense to use a 1" building supply when the line between the meter and the building is only 3/4"

I ask because initial WSFU calculations indicate a 3/4" building supply is inadequate (Hot 9.375 FU and Cold 10.875 FU, totaling 20.25 FU for the building supply).

Comment: Do you have fire sprinklers?

Comment: Do you have lawn sprinklers?

Comment: No fire or lawn sprinklers.

Comment: How are you calculating the total WSFU? Are you using table 610.3, and if so, have you followed note 3?

Answer (score 1):

Increasing the pipe size will not hurt anything. Mine is actually 1". It will also make it easy to upgrade in the future if you want. You can do this without changing your existing meter. The pipe you are using will eventually seal itself off with corrosion. Any type of mechanical action on the pipes and fittings can cause corrosion to flake off and could restrict the water flow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use a 1” meter on a 3/4” supply. However, before you change your existing meter and supply lines, I’d check

1. build up in your supply line,
2. verify distance from meter to house falls within the code allowed in Table P2910.2,
3. verify if supply service is not all uphill,
4. verify if problem area is on second floor only,
5. are neighbors experiencing the same problems,
6. did you or previous owner install fire sprinklers or lawn sprinklers?

Comment: I actually ask if a 1" supply could be used on a 3/4" meter (and if that would make any sense).  1) Every place I've been able to inspect pipe interiors has show significant corrosion/scaling. 2) Meter is 40' from building, 3' below floor level. Static pressure at floor level measures 65 psi. 3) Supply lines in crawl space are level. 4) Single story building. 5) Neighbor have reported flow issues. Galvanized steel pipes are notorious for corrosion/scaling. Area homes are approaching 70 years in age. 5) No fire or lawn sprinklers.